# how to return MySqlDataReader reader result into a List<DateTime> mylist

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

First, I'm using the db method to retrieve database record

```
public void db()
{
    string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd='';SslMode=none";

    using (MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = mcon.CreateCommand())
    {
        mcon.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT dates FROM abctable";

        using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result.Text += reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("dates"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, I can get two database record in the dates column
2018050120180503. How can I put these record into a `List<DateTime> mylist`?

Currently, the dates are just hard coded

For instance

```
 List<DateTime> mylist = new List<DateTime> { DateTime.ParseExact("20180509", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) };
```

Any idea? Thank you

Cannot download NuGet:

[image]

Comment: Don't store datetime, ints (or anything else that is not a string ) in a database as a string unless its a string, this is your friendly tip for the day

Comment: You may also want to check out the [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) framework.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) you can simplify the database access to

```
public List<DateTime> getDates() {
    string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd='';SslMode=none";
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connString)) {
        return connection.Query<DateTime>("SELECT dates FROM abctable").ToList();            
    }
}
```

Assuming that the `dates` in `abctable` are stored as actual dates in the database.

And then populate your list by calling the function.

```
List<DateTime> mylist = getDates();
```

Comment: @epiphany should be able to get it via nuget in the IDE https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper

Comment: can i download it using visual studio

Comment: @epiphany visual studio IS the IDE. So yes you would get it in visual studio via nuget

Comment: @epiphany No. nuget is the image you showed. Type in *Dapper* and it should filter for that

Comment: Mysql.Data.MysqlClient.MysqlConnection does not contain a definition for 'Query and no etension method 'Query' could be found

Comment: @epiphany my friend you need to add a `using Dapper;` to get access to the extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this class:

```
public static class DB
{
    private static readonly string ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd='';SslMode=none";

    private static IEnumerable<T> GetData(string sql, Action<MySqlParameterCollection> SetParameters, Func<IDataRecord, T> transformRecord)
    {
        using (var mcon = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, mcon))
        {
            if (SetParameters != null) SetParameters(cmd.Parameters);
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    yield return transformRecord(rdr);
                }
                rdr.Close();
            }
        }   
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates()
    {           
        return GetData("SELECT dates FROM abctable", null,
             r => (DateTime)r["dates"]);
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var myList = DB.GetDates().ToList();
```

You can add additional public methods to it that follow the same pattern as `GetDates()` for reading different tables in the database. Here is an example that shows how to use the `SetParameters` argument to use prepared statements/parameterized queries:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates(int ID)
{           
    return GetData("SELECT dates FROM abctable WHERE ID= @ID", 
         p => {
            p.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = ID;
         },
         r => (DateTime)r["dates"]);
}
```

You will also want an additional private method for supporting INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements, but I've shown enough here you should be able to write it on your own now.